# iOS - calling a web application from within an app

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, cordova, appcelerator

I have a quick question regarding to mobile development, I'm new at this, so please excuse me if I have some mistaken concepts. The scenario and question is the following:

I have a mobile site developed under .Net Framework 4.0, MVC3, Jquery Mobile, HTML5, and CSS3 that looks and works really well from any mobile browser: iOS Safari, Opera Mobile, Android Browser and Blackberry Browser.

I would like to create an app that has a browser in it with the address bar hidden to show this web application and don't let the user see the web address of this web application. The reason why I want this behaviour is this: we have a banking web application site that is intended to be used only through the mobile application. We don't want to create separate apps for each platform, so we would like to use some of those multiplatform frameworks like Phonegap, Appcelerator or such.

I only want to know if it's possible to get this achievement on Phonegap or something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done really easily using Appcelerator.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.0/Titanium.UI.WebView

Code:

```
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({url:'http://www.appcelerator.com'});
var window = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
window.add(webview);
window.open({modal:true});
```

However, if the app is only using that one webview and no other form of functionality, Apple could well reject it for not using any native functions.

See this note in their documentation...

> 12.3: Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a
>   collection of links, may be rejected

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good one about the Webclipping comment, have recently had an app rejected along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

if all you are going to do is host the app inside the webView then I would suggest that PhoneGap is better suited for that approach to mobile application development.

Appcelerator utilizes the native controls/ UI of the platform to build applications and since it is not your intention to use them it is just extra baggage.